# The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I'm getting an error when trying to join against multiple tables in a query:

**The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts**

It's confusing because it makes it seem like I'm using different contexts within the query but I'm not:

```
public static IQueryable<Company> GetAll(bool supportsMMAT)
            {
                return from c in Context.Companies
                            join v in Context.Vehicles on c.CompanyIdNumber equals v.CompanyIdNumber
                            join mt in Context.ModemTypes on v.ModemTypeId equals mt.Id
                            where !c.CompanyShutOff
                                && (!supportsMMAT || mt.Model == "MMAT")
                            select c;
            }
```

Any ideas? I'm using the EF4 CTP5 code first approach, if that makes any difference...

Comment: Is your Context property returning a new Context every call?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it was doing, my "ContextWorker" class that I use to statically access the data context was meant for web apps and was storing the context in httpruntime. However, I was running this from a test case so httpruntime wasn't available and it was creating new contexts. Please post your comment as a new answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can happen if your Context property returns a new instance every time.