# The query contains references to items defined on a different data context

Tags: linq

I have 2 var from same DBs, after union:

```
var projectedP1 = P1.Select(x => new Project_test { 
                                     ID_inString = x.ID.ToString(), 
                                     col1 = x.col1, 
                                     col2 = x.col2, 
                                     col3 = x.col3 });
var union = projectedP1.Union(P2);
```

when P1 alone or P2 alone, everything is fine
But when 2 is union, i get this in run-time:

The query contains references to items defined on a different data context.

I tried this similar post, but dun understand. ANyone has any idea?

[The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503202/the-specified-linq-expression-contains-references-to-queries-that-are-associated)

Comment: Well it's clearly to do with how P1 and P2 are created, which you haven't shown us. Presumably they're from different data contexts. I also assume you're the same user who asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884900/need-to-cast-explicitly-thru-anonymous-type-in-union - why are you using a different user account?

Comment: yes, same person, because i haven't registered. basically is create a dbml (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399400.aspx) for P1 using database A, another for P2 using database B

Comment: Ah, you never said they were from different *databases*. You basically can't do it on the LINQ to SQL side then - it's not like it can result in a UNION SQL query, is it?

Comment: at design time,database A &  database B 2 different servers, but run-time, they are same.is it the limitation of LINQ?

Comment: If they're separate databases, it doesn't matter whether they happen to be on the same server or not - you won't be able to do the union at the database side.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, LINQ sounds like weird to me

Comment: Well ignoring the LINQ part of things, how would you suggest running a single query using data from two different databases?

Answer (score 13):

You can never join objects from two different contexts; because the union is compiled into a database query, it wouldn't know how to execute it since multiple DB's are not supported.  The best you can do is to call ToList() on each query separately, which will execute the database queries, and do a LINQ-to-Objects union.  This is entirely an iterative process.

Comment: You don't need to call ToList - just AsEnumerable will do: `P1.AsEnumerable().Union(P2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... You'd also have to do it on P2 because that would have to be executed against its context, would it not?  I guess here since it's the second resultset, not executed within the context of the first operation, it would pass through fine and wouldn't attempt to translate the union as part of its query...

Comment: No, you don't have to do it on P2 because just doing it on P1 means it'll use the implementation in Enumerable, treating P1 as an `IEnumerable<T>` already.